# Clear HTML5 Appcache when offline

Tags: html, cache-manifest

I have a webapp that works offline.
I would like to set an expiration date to the cache so if the user does not reconnect to the server for a certain amount of time the cache is cleared and the user cannot use the application anymore.

I think the timer part is easy but I cannot find any way to delete programmatically the cache when I'm offline. I had found the way only when I'm online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to programmatically delete the appcache, you have to respond to a request for the manifest with a 404.  There is some interest at the W3C in [extending the current offline capabilities](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2013JanMar/0977.html), you might consider getting your [use case added to the list](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Webapps/AppCacheUseCases).